# No module named scipy.lib.six even if scipy is installed

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I installed `scipy` and `numpy` using `apt-get` on ubuntu and it was working fine until I tried using `scikit-image`. It seems that there is a module named `six` inside `scipy.lib` which is not present in the scipy. And hence I am getting

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/ndimage/_ni_support.py", line 35, in <module>
    from scipy.lib.six import integer_types, string_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

Is there a workaround for installing the `six` module?
My scipy version is `0.13.3`.

**EDIT** : It turns out that the `six` module is indeed the same package known by the name `six`. I uninstalled `six` and `python-scipy` and while reinstalling scipy I got the following error

```
W: pycompile:160: dangling symlink skipped: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/lib/decorator.py (../../decorator.py)
W: pycompile:160: dangling symlink skipped: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/lib/six.py (../../six.py)
```

**RE-EDIT** : I think I figured out the problem. While installing scipy, it tries to make a symlink to the already installed `six` module inside the `dist-packages`. But catch is that scipy is installed inside `/usr/lib/` and `six` inside `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: As a side note, `six` is a set of utilities that allows code that runs on both python-2 and python-3 to be written. It is available in scipy 0.15.1 which I have.

Comment: I've already got `six`. Here the module is being imported from `scipy.lib` which is kindda different.

Comment: Without installing `six` first, I used `apt-get` to install `scipy` on my VM (that's 0.13.3 like yours), and I was able to import the two variables listed above. Also, `scipy.lib.six` -is- the python compatibility package, I got that line from `help(scipy.lib.six)` in the console.

Comment: Interesting, I have two installs of `scipy`, one in `/usr/lib` and another in `/usr/local/lib`. I seem to be using the latter, as the former doesn't seem to have the `six` library inside the `lib/` directory. I wonder how to fix this bug upstream...

Comment: I have filed a [ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-scipy/+bug/1533634) on the launchpad for `python-scipy`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows you can download the package as provided by Gohlke:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#six

Otherwise you can download the wheel (.whl extension) and install this using pip.

Comment: I like the Gohlke page a lot, as I have to deal with Windows machines.

Comment: I'm on linux and I don't think the problem is with the python2-3 compatibility package. I've already got that. Here the missing module is built inside the `scipy.lib` module

Comment: I am fairly certain that it is the python2-3 compatibility package, albeit that it is included in scipy. If I were you I would uninstall the six package and reinstall the scipy package. (BTW are you sure you are working on the proper python environment; 2 or 3)

Comment: @DickKniep Yes! You are right. I tried that and edited the question. There is some issue with creating the symlink for it.